# How to Send Variables on .SetRequestData on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a API integration on my Excel WorkSheet using VBA and I'm trying to send user input on a cell sent to a RequestHeader in order to find a product on the server

I've tried importing the data directly from the sheet onto a string and then sending that string as the value for the header but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm new to this whole VBA stuff so I don't honestly know if that's possible. Here's what I've tried:

```
Sub GetCompanyInformation()
Dim hReq As Object, JSON As Dictionary
Dim i As Long
Dim var As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = Sheet1

'create our URL string and pass the user entered information to it
Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "My API URL Goes Here"

Dim cod As String
    cod = ws.[MYCELL]

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "cache-control", "no-cache"
        .SetRequestHeader "data_filter", ""
        .SetRequestHeader "data", "products"
        .SetRequestHeader "data_id", cod
        .Send
    End With
[...]
```

It returns me an empty string. However if I send the request with the same number I add on my cell as such:

```
  [...]
     Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "cache-control", "no-cache"
        .SetRequestHeader "data_filter", ""
        .SetRequestHeader "data", "products"
        .SetRequestHeader "data_id", "1234"
        .Send
    End With
```

It Works, and it returns me the data I need. Am I doing something wrong? Can I get the variable data on a Request Header?

Comment: Are you confident `cod` has the value you expect?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes, I can confirm using the msgbox that `cod` has the value I input on the cell.

Comment: In that case it should work, so something else must be going on.  Have you tried using and HTTP debugger (like Fiddler for example) to compare the two requests?

Comment: I haven't yet. I'll try that.

Comment: Also, try Trim$(cod) just in case